# grails 2.3 render textarea newlines as line breaks in gsp

Tags: grails

I'm running grails 2.3.  The new default settings have XSS prevention.  I have a textarea a user can enter data in including line breaks.

I'm having trouble rendering the newlines as line breaks.

Text area value:

```
Something
is
happening
here
```

What gets output in the webpage:

```
<span class="description_text">Something&lt;br/&gt;is&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;happening&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;here.</span>
```

What the rendered GSP should look like:

```
Something<br/>is<br/>happening<br/>here<br/>
```

Things I've tried:

```
out << content?.replace('\n', '<br/>').encodeAsHTML()
out << content?.encodeAsHTML().replace('\n', '<br/>')
out << content?.encodeAsHTML()
```

My settings in Config.groovy:

```
// Legacy setting for codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "html"

// GSP settings
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs - NOOOO because we ouput html tags in our taglibs, as do some plugins.
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
        // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
        filteringCodecForContentType {
            //'text/html' = 'html'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up fine-graining individual taglibs and tag lib methods to set the output to 'raw' depending on how much I cared about XSS prevention for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the JSP style syntax to avoid the encoding safety of a gsp.  Can you give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case when you would like to allow user only to add line breaks you should be able to use something like:

```
out << content?.encodeAsHTML().replace('&lt;br/&gt;', '<br/>')
```

Although it's not the prettiest solution, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
out << content?.encodeAsHTML().replace('\n', '<br/>').encodeAsRaw()
```

This worked for me when I wanted to paste some text from the DB into a template. Now you first escape any script nasties and then transform the newlines into br tags.